# Jira Restful api to get any completed sprint Comitted and delivered data

Tags: jira, jira-rest-java-api

I am writing a Java command like program to fetch Scrum information using Jira Rest API. I am not seeing any restful api to find a given completed sprint Committed and Delivered Story points or velocity chart information.

Can anyone help me out with what service I have to call to get it ?

I am using a raw rest call using basic authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the answer varies for the Jira installation type

### Jira Cloud

There's no direct way to get data about a sprint through the api, but I believe [`POST /rest/api/3/expression/eval`](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-jira-expressions/#api-rest-api-3-expression-eval-post) would be your best option. From there you could find all the issues from your intended sprint with a JQL like `Sprint=4`, and then tally the story points. It's not perfect, but the best I'm aware of.

### Jira Server/Data Center

Based on your version you may have to take the same approach as for Cloud, however some older versions of Jira have the [Agile API](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira-software/REST/7.3.1/#agile/1.0/sprint) which would probably speed things along